# Name of 1980s Pandemic mini-series

Tags: story-identification, tv

I wonder if anyone can recall this show. It doesn't seem to be widely remembered as I never see it on any relevant lists.

A 1980s miniseries set in Antarctica after a worldwide pandemic. Survivors consist of Antarctic research base staff, and at least one nuclear submarine crew that turns up later. The various international bases try to unite to survive. They have a problem with men outnumbering women. After some time the sub does a tour of the Pacific to search for survivors, they visit Tokyo and San Francisco but find no signs of life. One of the crew leaves the sub in SF to try to find family.

It was basically a US show, but Japan features somewhat prominently, so was possibly a co-production.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [*Virus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_(1980_film)) (1980).

It's a film, but it was later cut for television. Doesn't exactly match--they go to Washington DC instead of San Francisco, for one--but it's close. Post-pandemic Antarctic refuge, nuclear submarine, and so forth.

Comment: Ah, wow that sounds too much like it for it not to be it! Especially the edited down for TV version. But just a telemovie not a miniseries, that probably hampered my search. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Your description is similar to certain aspects of [On The Beach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Beach_%28novel%29), especially the crew member in SF part.  The story was centered in Australia, not Antarctica, and featured a visit to San Diego, not Tokyo.  An adaptation perhaps?

Comment: Ah that's very interesting. Reading the wikipedia synopsis it looks like I may have conflated two different submarine voyages to the post-apocalyptic Northern hemisphere! The crew member leaving the sub in SF for family reasons is from the _On The Beach_ movie. Thanks indeed.