# A TV-Movie or an Episode of a Series where someone is turned into a cyborg when running through a doorway

Tags: story-identification

I have seen this some 15 or so years ago **on TV**. That was around the years 1999 to 2002 I guess. Here's what I can scarcely remember:

I remember it being real people, not animated.

The theme was science-fiction.

There was a group of people, possibly in their late teens / early tweens. Men and women.

The part of the plot I remember was them being aboard a crashed(?) spaceship, they had to cross through a doorway to get to the control room (or some other important part) of said ship. But there was a twist: They had to pass through the doorway at some specific interval, if they ran through at the wrong time they would be caught inside it and turned into a cyborg(?).

Which is what happened, someone got caught and then I think they started to shoot at the others.

---

Now that is not much to work with I know. But it's all I remember. The one flashy scene from almost 2 decades ago.

I can confirm it not being [Earth Star Voyager](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095077/). I have stumbled upon that movie via the suggestions coming up when creating a new question and subsequently watched it over the course of the last 3 hours.

I can also confirm it not being [Cyborg](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120458/). Although I can recommend this 1999 movie to anyone that enjoys tech-horror.

Comment: ^_^ Although ESV was quite the film...

Comment: Can you recall any other salient details?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_(1999_film)? If so, it already has an [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/47594/51379), (so normally I’d just want to close as duplicate), but this question has a bounty, so....

Comment: Also, if not this, was the “turning into a cyborg” instantaneous or something that would happen after being captured?

Comment: @Adamant it's def not Virus. Virus plays aboard a nautical ship and the villain gets turned into a cyborg more or less willingly there. || From what I can remember, the turning into a cyborg happens in a montage while the person is captured inside the doorway.

Comment: Are you possibly misremembering some of the details? Some parts of it sound similar to [this scene from Superman 3](https://youtu.be/YuSsSwg9MXs).

Comment: @Wikis it might just well be that scene. Fits everything but the age. Which would make sense because at that age everyone older than me looked more or less the same :) I'm still wondering if there's another movie with almost the same scene, but please write it up as an answer if you'd like to :D

Comment: Thx for acceptance & bounty!

Comment: @Wikis let's honest: There's not much competition^^

Comment: I hope it was what you were looking for then!

Comment: @Wikis it strikes a memory/remembrance and it's the only answer. So it seems to be pretty much that movie^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my comment above (which the questioner asked me to write up as an answer), I think it is this creepy scene from [Superman 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_III):

This is how it fits the question

- Real people, not animated
- Walking through a doorway, becomes a cyborg (not quite, but the visuals do look a lot like a doorway and the woman *nearly* becomes a cyborg<sup>1</sup>)
- *"Someone got caught and then I think they started to shoot at the others"* - exactly what happens in this scene
- Superman 3 was from 1983 so it could have been seen on TV at a later date.

One difference: it's not a crashed spaceship but a giant "supercomputer".

<sub>1 Later the "computer components" were removed, so apparently she was just covered with them rather suffering a permanent alteration.</sub>

Comment: Oh shoot, my bad. I've seen it on the telly at that time, not in a theatre. I should add that to the question!

Comment: I, too, thought of this scene, so @Wikis beat me to it.

Comment: That stupid movie is so frigging tonally inconsistent. Keep in mind that this same movie was about 60% mugging by the then-hottest comedian in America.